# Debugging with an assemble program with GDB

Tags: gdb

Here is my question:

I wrote a piece of code of assemble. It could read a file, transform the content to the uppercase and print the outputs in a newfile.

I complie and link the assemble code with:

> as -gstabs read-files.s -o read-files.o
>
> ld read-files.o -o read-files

And a test like "./read-files input-file output-file" works well.

But what if I want to debug this piece of code with gdb? I tried, but:

when I set the breakpoint and args of target code in gdb with:

> (gdb) b *_start+1
>
> (gdb) run test-file TEST-FILE

It will end with a segmentfault immediately.

Can I really debug this code like what I just stated aboved? Thanks

And the assemble code is here:

```
 .section .data
 .equ SYS_OPEN, 5
 .equ SYS_WRITE, 4
 .equ SYS_READ, 3
 .equ SYS_CLOSE, 6
 .equ SYS_EXIT, 1
 .equ O_RDONLY, 0
 .equ O_CREAT_WRONLY_TRUNC, 03101
 .equ STDIN, 0
 .equ STDOUT, 1
 .equ STDERR, 2
 .equ LINUX_SYSCALL, 0x80
 .equ END_OF_FILE, 0
 .equ NUMBER_ARGUMENTS, 2

 .section .bss
 .equ BUFFER_SIZE, 500
 .lcomm BUFFER_DATA, BUFFER_SIZE

 .section .text
 .equ ST_SIZE_RESERVE, 8
 .equ ST_FD_IN, -4
 .equ ST_FD_OUT, -8
 .equ ST_ARGC, 0
 .equ ST_ARGV_0, 4
 .equ ST_ARGV_1, 8
 .equ ST_ARGV_2, 12

 .globl _start
_start:
 movl %esp, %ebp
 subl $ST_SIZE_RESERVE, %esp

open_files:
open_fd_in:
 movl $SYS_OPEN, %eax
 movl ST_ARGV_1(%ebp), %ebx
 movl $O_RDONLY, %ecx
 movl $0666, %edx
 int $LINUX_SYSCALL

store_fd_in:
 movl %eax, ST_FD_IN(%ebp)

open_fd_out:
 movl $SYS_OPEN, %eax
 movl ST_ARGV_2(%ebp), %ebx
 movl $O_CREAT_WRONLY_TRUNC, %ecx
 movl $0666, %edx
 int $LINUX_SYSCALL

store_fd_out:
 movl %eax, ST_FD_OUT(%ebp)

read_loop_begin:
 movl $SYS_READ, %eax
 movl ST_FD_IN(%ebp), %ebx
 movl $BUFFER_DATA, %ecx
 movl $BUFFER_SIZE, %edx
 int $LINUX_SYSCALL

 cmpl $END_OF_FILE, %eax
 jle end_loop

continue_read_loop:
 pushl $BUFFER_DATA
 pushl %eax
 call convert_to_upper
 popl %eax
 addl $4, %esp

 movl %eax, %edx
 movl $SYS_WRITE, %eax
 movl ST_FD_OUT(%ebp), %ebx
 movl $BUFFER_DATA, %ecx
 int $LINUX_SYSCALL

 jmp read_loop_begin

end_loop:
 movl $SYS_CLOSE, %eax
 movl ST_FD_OUT(%ebp), %ebx
 int $LINUX_SYSCALL

 movl $SYS_CLOSE, %eax
 movl ST_FD_IN(%ebp), %ebx
 int $LINUX_SYSCALL

 movl $SYS_EXIT, %eax
 movl $0, %ebx
 int $LINUX_SYSCALL

 .equ LOWERCASE_A, 'a'
 .equ LOWERCASE_Z, 'z'
 .equ UPPER_CONVERSION, 'A' - 'a'
 .equ ST_BUFFER_LEN, 8
 .equ ST_BUFFER, 12

convert_to_upper:
 pushl %ebp
 movl %esp, %ebp

 movl ST_BUFFER(%ebp), %eax
 movl ST_BUFFER_LEN(%ebp), %ebx
 movl $0, %edi

 cmpl $0, %ebx
 je end_convert_loop

convert_loop:
 movb (%eax, %edi, 1), %cl
 cmpb $LOWERCASE_A, %cl
 jl next_byte
 cmpb $LOWERCASE_Z, %cl
 jg next_byte

 addb $UPPER_CONVERSION, %cl
 movb %cl, (%eax, %edi, 1)

next_byte:
 incl %edi
 cmpl %edi, %ebx
 jne convert_loop

end_convert_loop:
 movl %ebp, %esp
 popl %ebp
 ret
```